# JDBC ResultSet is giving only one row although there are many rows in table?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am having many rows in table and I ran the same query on my database which is MySql but java ResultSet is only giving the first row of the table. Here is my code.

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllAlbumsName(Integer uid) {
    ArrayList<String>allAlbumsName = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        String qstring = "SELECT albumname FROM picvik_picture_album WHERE " +
                "uid = '" + uid + "';";

        System.out.println(qstring);
        connection = com.picvik.util.MySqlConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
        ptmt = connection.prepareStatement(qstring);
        resultSet = ptmt.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("albumname"));
            allAlbumsName.add(resultSet.getString("albumname"));
        }

        resultSet.close();
        ptmt.close();
        connection.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return allAlbumsName;
}
```

Comment: It would be rather difficult to get more than one of anything without a loop.

Comment: @Brian You could always manually "unwind" all of your loops.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if(resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("albumname"));
            allAlbumsName.add(resultSet.getString("albumname"));
        }
```

If you would like to get all rows, it should be:

```
while(resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString("albumname"));
        allAlbumsName.add(resultSet.getString("albumname"));
    }
```

The [while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) statement continually executes a block of statements while a particular condition is true

Note: As @BalusC commented, your code would introduce SQL Injection attack, it is better to use ptmt.set... Instead of constructing SQL String manually.

Answer (score 3):

try `while(resultSet.next()) {`

instead of `if (resultSet.next()) {`

Answer (score 2):

Change `if (resultSet.next()) {` to `while (resultSet.next()) {`