# ResultSet next() is returning only one row

Tags: jdbc, resultset, multiple-results

I am having this method

```
public List<Course> getCourses() throws InvalidCourseDataException {
    ArrayList<Course> allCoursesFromDB = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection dbConnection = null;

    String getFromTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM courses";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(getFromTableSQL);

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            String courseCategory = resultSet.getString("course_category");
            String courseTitle = resultSet.getString("course_title");

            int courseId = resultSet.getInt("course_id");

            Date startDate = resultSet.getTimestamp("starting_date");
            Date endDate = resultSet.getDate("ending_date");
            String description = resultSet.getString("description");
            int teacherId = resultSet.getInt("teacher_id");

            Course course = new Course(courseCategory, courseTitle, startDate, endDate);
            course.setCourseId(courseId);
            course.setTeacherId(teacherId);
            course.setDescription(description);

            addParticipantsIdToCourse(course);
            allCoursesFromDB.add(course);
        }
```

The getDBConnection() method is
    private static Connection getDBConnection() {

```
    System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {
        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return dbConnection;

}
```

My problem is that resultSet.next() is returning only the first row from DB. I'am sure that I have multiple rows. I saw [JDBC ResultSet is giving only one row although there are many rows in table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106691/jdbc-resultset-is-giving-only-one-row-although-there-are-many-rows-in-table) that question but it really doesn't answer my :)

Comment: how do you figure it's only returning one? Debugged? Some output?

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the right database?

Comment: When I debug I see that only one course is added to my ArrayList. And yes I am absolutely sure about the DB

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the question. I found my mistake. ResultSet next() method is working fine, but I've changed its value in my addParticipantsIdToCourse(course) method :)